# Azure SQL timeouts for first request after some period

Tags: azure-sql-database

We have Azure SQL database in Standard S0 tier (10DTU), one table has more than 4milion rows and it is properly indexed.
It is a test/development enviroment and only I am using this app.
After some X period of time first request on that database/table with small dataset requested timeouts!?
At that moment DTU percentage is 100%, but after few requests everything  is working perfect for the same request (and larger dataset - DTU is max 10-20% for heavy use).
Picture of max DTU units in attached.

Do you have any advice other than going to a higher paid tier?

[image]

NEW ...
This is now same database for testing without any backend connected to it!

Tested from SSMS

First Query after few hours of inactivity (Execution time is 3min)

[image]

Same Query second time (Execution time is 12 sec) !!!!

[image]

Any ideas!?

Answer (score 0):

It behaves like a serverless database.

Well, Azure SQL Database are, of course, a virtualization of a SQL Server instance so don't expect it to work exactly like your on-prem.

I suggest you to try other family version like S1 and test. Performances might improve.

Also try to

1. Pause it for 1h
2. Run some SELECT to wake it up
3. Run your query

maybe you might need to setup this scenario to automate your database wake-up

Comment: Database is not in any "sleep mode".. Before requested dataset (from large table) there is a request on small table that works fine. I tried higer DTU tiers but for that "few" first requests after some time of inactiviti are not helping.

Answer (score 0):

Throttling is the probably the cause of this issue. When throttling occurs you usually see the symptoms you described, connection timeouts, poor performance.

You can see connection timeouts with the following query:

```
select * 
from sys.event_log 
where event_type <> 'connection_successful' and
start_time >= CAST(FLOOR(CAST(getdate() AS float)) AS DATETIME)
order by start_time desc
```

The following query tells you when you need to scale up.

```
SELECT     
(COUNT(end_time) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_cpu_percent > 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(end_time) AS 'CPU Fit Percent',
(COUNT(end_time) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_log_write_percent > 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(end_time) AS 'Log Write Fit Percent',
(COUNT(end_time) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_data_io_percent > 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(end_time) AS 'Physical Data Read Fit Percent'
FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats
--service level objective (SLO) of 99.9% <= go to next tier
```

When avg_log_write_percent is at 100% or near 100% then throthling occurs. Try to scale up tiers before starting IO intensive workloads.

Try to implement batching on your IO workloads to control those DTU spikes. Please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/performance-improve-use-batching?wt.mc_id=MVP) documentation to know how.

In addition, try to implement retry logic on your application as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/transient-fault-handling?wt.mc_id=MVP).

Comment: In a controlled environment when only I am hitting the server with the same request (that is usually under 500ms) there shouldn't be any difference for first request after some period and succeeding requests!?